# Generic Chaos Java

Tags: java, generics

I use two Interfaces:

```
public interface Receiver<T> {

  public void receive(T obj);

  public Set<Class<? extends T>> getInterests();

}

public interface Distributor<T> extends Receiver<T> {

 public void register(Receiver<T> receiver);

}
```

My problem that I want to register a Distributor in a Distributor e.g.
`Distributor<Object>` ==register==> `Distributor<String>`

My first thought was to change the register method to `register(Receiver<? extends T> receiver).` But if I want to get the Classes the receiver is intrested in the Method getInterests would return something like
  `Set<Class<? extends ? extends T>>`. 
Indirect I get something like `Set<Class<? extends T>>` but I experienced that transitiv wildcards are not possible in Java.

Got anyone an idea?

**EDIT:** As an example:

```
public void register(Receiver<? extends T> receiver){
  Set<Class<? extends T>> interests = receiver.getInterests();
  //Problem because receiver.getInterests is 
  //Set<Class<? extends ? extends T>>
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a line of code which doesn't compile for you?  The code looks like it will compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that Java generics are completely invariant, unless you make them variant using `? extends` or `? super` wildcards.

A `Set<Class<? extends T>>` can only hold expressions of exactly the compile-time type `Class<? extends T>`.  `Class<String>` is not the same type as `Class<? extends T>` (even though it is convertible to that type).

You want a set that can hold any type that is convertible to `Class<? extends T>`.

That would be a `Set<? extends Class<? extends T>>`

Comment: `Class` is final right? How can there be anything which extends Class?

Comment: @Codebender: `extends` actually means "convertible to".  `Class<String>` is convertible to `Class<? extends Object>` (though not to `Class<Object>`; you need _both_ `? extends` wildcards).

Comment: @Codebender `Class<T>` can have subtypes via generics even though the class is final and cannot be subclassed. `extends` has a broader meaning when used in a bound.

Comment: @SLaks Seems to be the right answer. Now I got some minor problems like in my Distributor I don't know how to call receive as I don't really know what T is. But I will think about it. Maybe I find  a better solution in general for this generic chaos. Thank you SLaks

Answer (score 1):

You could add a helper method that uses a type variable instead of wildcard

```
public void register(Receiver<? extends T> receiver)
{
    register2(receiver);
}

private <S extends T> void register2(Receiver<S> receiver)
{
    Set<Class<? extends S>> interests = receiver.getInterests();
    ...
}
```

On the other hand, method

```
    public Set<Class<? extends T>> getInterests();
```

is probably intended to return a covariant `Set`, or, read-only set. Ideally wildcard should be used

```
    public Set<? extends Class<? extends T>> getInterests();
```

but I know, there are too many damn wildcards...